# PHP not running on nginx with Debian 8

Tags: php, nginx, debian

I just configured my Debian 8 server with nginx. I can browse html files. I use `let's encrypt` which works succesfully, also with redirecting http to https automatically.

What does **not** work is PHP. Also a simple `info.php` file with

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

does not work.

On browser client my error message is:

> 404 Not Found nginx/1.6.2

Nginx' error log shows this:

> 2018/05/29 19:22:57 [error] 1879#0: *1592 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/info.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: *ip_address*, server: , request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", host: "*domain*"

My nginx configuration is:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    server_name my-server.de www.my-server.de;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ /.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    include snippets/ssl-my-server.de.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
}
```

Even if i move `info.php` to `/usr/share/nginx/html` then the client browser just downloads the `info.php` file.

I went through all steps in [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-debian-8) guide. But still it isn't working. So how to fix that?

Comment: Of course I did

Comment: Did you restart web server after changing nginx config, and php-fpm? make sure you should give 777 permission to `/var/run/php5-fpm.sock`

Comment: I tried that too: same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not added in SSL listen port 443, and ssl config of let's encrypt, please comment 301 redirect, test PHP, than go for SSL configuration see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-debian-8

I have seen you have added SSL configuration, you need fix as below nginx configuration, after redirect, `PHP` should be configured on `443 not on 80`.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name my-server.de www.my-server.de;
    # Redirect to HTTPS    
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    include snippets/ssl-my-server.de.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;


    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ /.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting answer, I see PHP 5 is now running, :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm using:

```
    upstream php {
            server 127.0.0.1:9000;
            server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock down;
    }


    location ~* \.php$ {
            root /var/www/html/;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass php;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
```

Comment: Applying this does not change anything for me. I don't understand why  don't find any solution for such a typical use-case?

Comment: @unlimited101 Have you put it in the correct `server { ... }` block? Can you paste your current/changed config?

Comment: Sure I put it in the upper block and removed this block: ``location ~ /.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }``